# Can't find pages' URL after database renew Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site since a couple year hosted on a trusted domain. A couple weeks ago i forgot to renew my mySql database and obviously the site went down. To give my user a way to contact my shop i created another index.php and, after saving the old index.php given by the Wordpress theme, i deployed it on the server using Filezilla. Yesterday my domain was renewed and they told me everything is working, so i deleted my new index.php page and i deployed back the one got from the WP theme.

Now the home page works wonder, but if i try to show any other page i get a "Not Found - Requested URL was not found on this server". I tried to create another simple page to see if that works, and i get the same error. I didn't change anything in my file system bar index.php, and i'm pretty sure that's the one i used to have before my database went down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you logged into the Admin and re-saved your permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks @mevius for your answer. Unfortunatly that was one of the first things i tried and it didn't work. What i ended up doing was download the content of my MySql DB and exported all the tables into another DB that shared the host with the first one. After doing that i edited the wp-config file changing the DB name and my website works like a charm again. Thanks!